# Convert CSV to vector form in R language

Tags: r, csv

I would like to convert CSV file to a vector in R.
The CSV file looks like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nPOu4HEelx9h99EXxFLiS9YOgiK2pZADVd1XnRhZpWs/edit#gid=0)! and is shown self contained within the question below:

I would like the form of the vector to be: c(A = 1, B = 2, C = 56)

```
Lines <- "Parameter,Value1,Value2,Value3
A,1,1,1
B,2,4,2
C,56,5,7"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: What about other column values? For only 1st column you can do `setNames(df$Value1, df$Parameter)`

Comment: Please try to make your question self-contained. I have done it for you this time.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to transpose the data then

```
DFt <- setNames(as.data.frame(t(DF[-1])), DF[[1]])
```

giving this data frame:

```
DFt
##        A B  C
## Value1 1 2 56
## Value2 1 4  5
## Value3 1 2  7
```

so, for example, the first row is:

```
DFt[1, ]
##        A B  C
## Value1 1 2 56
```

or as a named vector:

```
unlist(DFt[1, ])
##  A  B  C 
##  1  2 56
```

A list of named vectors, one per row of `DFt` can be formed like this:

```
lapply(split(DFt, rownames(DFt)), unlist)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, G. Grothendieck. It works super well!